# c# DataAdapter.Fill performance improvement

Tags: c#, performance, dataadapter

I have a Firebird DataBase containing a contact list and, for each contact, as list of services and invoices.

The order of magnitude of the customer table is 10k and the invoices/services about 5 times the contacts size. The thing is that the tables contain lots of columns (up to 150). I know this is not ideal, unfortunately, I cannot redesign the database as it is imposed as is.

Now, I have a significant part of time (in fact, nearly 40-50%) spent in the pure fetching of the data using following code:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.BeginLoadData();
FbDataAdapter fda = new FbDataAdapter(command);
fda.Fill(dataTable);
dataTable.EndLoadData();
```

I am quite disappointed by the fact that fetching 30k rows takes about 20 seconds for the sole `Fill` call. Is there any hope to improve this part? Any alternative (possibly commercial) to improve this?

Comment: Why are you loading 30,000 rows? Are you making a report?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to load everything at once? If not then the easiest solution will be to implement some sort of paging (read: load a smaller number records at a time and then move on to the next bit).

Comment: sort of - yes. I use buffered approach because I need flexible and heavy search on the dataset. Memory-based search is MUCH, MUCH faster than server-side in this case...

Comment: I know about paging or similar - as mentioned, the problem then becomes the search as there are so many columns, it gets way easier to let client handle search routines... Think of  a "find all rows where any column contains a case-insensitive, accent-insensitive sub-string of the searched string"

Comment: I've run into performance issues populating datatables before. Whether this is applicabel to firebird I'm not sure, but this article might be of help (it helped me with MSSQL) - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/vendettamit/fastest-way-to-populate-datatable-from-database-using-idatareader/

Comment: Yep tried that as well - in fact, I compared your approach with Dapper and DataReader - Dapper gives the best result, but only in some cases and with a small percentage...

Comment: Just checked our approach - We load the data by derriving a `DataReader` from the query, then using the `Load` method on the `DataTable`. In our case, the data set is in excess of 100k rows, and we have to do this in memory for searching and cross referencing. I'm sorry to say, but we never found a way to improve it, but as is was part of a routine which synchronises two databases, we just let it run once an hour. Is there any way you can multithread the loading of paged data into multiple data tables and combine them afterwards? If

Comment: @Alex seems we're stuck at the same place... Actually, I wouldn't necessarily need to load the data into a `DataTable` - I only need ANY approach allowing me to access the fields of each "row" individually... But as said, `DataReader` isn't much better... Well, good thing is that this only hampers users once...

Comment: @neggenbe If you can deal with multiple datatables, my best suggestion would be to split your query into multiple queries to load a subset of data in each. Load these into multiple data tables, and have each load operation in its own task. So long as you can keep track of which subset is in which data table, you can search on them easily enough (possibly store them in a `DataSet` - you might be able to derrive a `DataView` accross multiple tables).

Comment: @Alex take a look at my answer below... I ended up with a quite interesting approach to split by columns, as there are so many that are not immediately useful!

Answer (score 2):

Well, as comments suggest, there is not much that can be done except consider the special case here. What I did is split the large number of **columns** (not rows) into two categories: preview columns and full (detail) data columns. The idea is to load the preview data all at once and the detail only on request, for one columns at a time.

Now just have a look at the times in the cases below:

```
Overall: 5 runs, >16k rows, time includes all code in the question!

Case 1: 4 preview fields (3 int, 1 float), 135(+4 preview) fields for full list
Preview queries:         1063.3470 ms
   Full queries:        25712.2665 ms

Case 2: 12 preview fields (3 int, 9 float), 127(+12 preview) fields for full list
Preview queries:         1457.1946 ms
   Full queries:        25735.5247 ms

Case 3: 13 preview fields (3 int, 9 float, 1 blob subtype 1), 126(+13 preview) fields for full list
Preview queries:     4023.9923 ms
   Full queries:    26777.5369 ms


250 Queries with "WHERE" contstraint on a foreign key
Returning 1052 row in total
Total execution time 10348.0545 ms
```

WOW! Loading time is 6 to 20 times faster than for the FULL list. Of course, I'll have an overhead when loading individual data... Well, after testing it, I queried DB with a "where" condition a foreign key. Each of the 250 queries I've run return, in average, 4 rows for an average execution time of 42 ms - time users have to wait each time the want to access DETAIL of a given row (which is on-click, so that's absolutely ok in my case).

Bottom line: splitting data is also the key here, although I've split data by columns, not by rows!!!!

Comment: That's a really neat approach! I hadn't considered splitting by column in this way, though in our system I'm not certain we'd be able to as all the columns are needed. It's definately something to keep in mind though, and quite a susprising set of times. I'd be curious to know if this performance impact is similar on MSSQL.